# Weak Linking in Swift

Tags: objective-c, swift, macos

I'm dealing with a scenario where there is an Objective-C class that I am weakly linking:

```
__attribute__((weak_import))
@interface MyClass : NSObject @end
```

I'm also using this class in my Swift code:

```
let myObject : MyClass = MyClass()
```

However, this always crashes when run in `swift_getObjCClassMetadata`, even if I'm only casting an object that's already of type `MyClass`

```
let myObject : MyClass = otherObj as? MyClass
```

Is there any way to successfully cast to, or utilize these classes from Swift?

Comment: Are you weak linking an entire framework or a single class?

Comment: A single class, in this.

Comment: Hmm, can't seem to reproduce this scenario, presumably since the library I created up for weak linking isn't set up the same way as yours.  Would you mind setting up a small project that reproduces the issue?

Comment: I'm going to sound a little crazy here, but I can't replicate it now in a new project, either. Experimenting...!

Comment: No worries, keep us updated.

Comment: After extended testing, I've come to the conclusion that this has a lot to do with how the main app is compiled. In my tests, creating an app from scratch loads the classes and can use them without issue.

Comment: I'd like to know this too: all answers on the web point to #availability() which is not useful here: it is only for OS features, not third-party frameworks.

Comment: @Daniel You can always detect the presence of an Objective-C class using `NSClassFromString("...") != nil`