# Weak linking of custom frameworks in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, swift3

I studied this question [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPFrameworks/Concepts/WeakLinking.html), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24591952/how-do-i-do-weak-linking-in-swift), and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35894754/weak-linking-in-swift), but I did not receive the desired answer.

We have a group of frameworks that my team has created. We are intending for some of these frameworks be weakly linked into iOS, watchOS, tvOS and OS X applications.

So, we have the rare case where #availablity doesn't work for us. Our frameworks all support iOS 8+, watchOS 2+, tvOS9+ and OS X Yosemite+.

How do you go about doing the old way of symbol checking we used to do in Objective-C but in Swift?

Comment: I too am looking into weak linking with Swift of custom frameworks. I'll post my answer if I get to one.

Comment: I just opened up a topic in the Swift Forums about this: https://forums.swift.org/t/weak-linking-of-frameworks-with-greater-deployment-targets/26017